# Calling refreshAllObjects in Core Data freezes UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I have two NSManagedObjectContexts in my project, one for main queue and the other for private queue. When my app starts, the main queue context fetches data from entity A and displays them in a table view. At the same time, it tries to delete invalid data in entity B, and this part of data doesn't need to be displayed at startup. However, when there are a few thousand records for entity A, calling method refreshAllObjects takes quite a long time. I'm not quite familiar with multithreading in Core Data, and I think there should be some ways to solve this.

Here's my code snippet.

```
// initialization
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
self.privateMoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
self.privateMoc.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;
self.mainMoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
self.mainMoc.parentContext = self.privateMoc;

// delete invalid data
[self.mainMoc performBlock:^{
    NSFetchRequest<CustomClass *> *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:MyEntity inManagedObjectContext:self.mainMoc];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isInvalid == 1"];
    NSError *error;
    NSBatchDeleteRequest *deleteRequest = [[NSBatchDeleteRequest alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest];
    [self.mainMoc executeRequest:deleteRequest error:&error];
    [self.mainMoc refreshAllObjects];   // this method takes a few seconds
}];
```

My guess is that since the delete operation is not UI related, maybe I can push this operation to private context so it becomes something like this:

```
[self.mainMoc performBlock:^{
    [self.privateMoc performBlock:^{
        // copy code above and change all mainMoc to privateMoc
        ......
    }];
}];
```

At this time, the main thread is not blocked, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way.

Comment: Yes, it is normal to have 2 contexts (or more). In my opinion you should have 1 context that is in background which is used to read and write. The other context is on main thread and is only used to read. When background context saves data it should use delegates to notify listeners that changes have been made so that the main context reloads data (or your screens reload data). Also use `NSFetchResultController` when dealing with lists of data instead of just reading them all.

Comment: @MaticOblak Thanks for your suggestion. May I ask why the background context should be used to both read and write while main thread context should be used to just read? In my opinion both read and write from database should be time consuming operations. Does Core Data have some optimization on read so that fetching a few data in main thread is acceptable?

Comment: Well the background one needs read so it can modify the objects it read. You do need read on main thread because some items may be lazily retrieved from database like referenced objects. It is possible to put read to background context as well but you then need to copy data to access them safely. To be honest it is exactly what I usually do. But fetch result controllers should be enough for you on the main thread to display data as you only display what you see, not all the objects at the same time. And your delete operation can fully be done on background context.

Comment: @MaticOblak I see. Also, in above code if one context(e.g. self.mainMoc) executes refreshAllObjects, other contexts also should run refreshAllObjects to synchronize the data if all contexts have fetched some data from the same entity in memory. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. A context is an in-memory reflection of your database. When one context modifies something in database then the other context should reload data. If multiple contexts update database "at the same time" a conflict may occur which you should resolve. But if only one context is designated for writing you should not need to handle conflicts.